# how to use soundtouch library in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, soundtouch

I had gone through the SoundTouch library i.e. [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/index.html) and build it as mention [here](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/README-SoundTouch-Android.html). But I am not getting is how to use this compiled library in my android project.So, anybody having any idea or example of how to use this library in android.I searched a lot but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're still looking I'm working on a wrapper - https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android

Comment: looking for the same to do pitch shifting and time stretching in a video, the link in the comments are not working so if any progress in it so please help.